# How to determine complexity of these operations?

Tags: c

I have implmented the stack using these date structures:

```
typedef struct node{
    StackEntry entry;
    struct node *next;
}Node;


typedef struct stack{
    Node *top;
}Stack;
```

How do I find the BigO for each of these operations below?

- StackEmpty(Stack *s)
- StackSize(Stack *s)
- Push(Node *e, Stack *s)
- Pop(Node *e, Stack *s)

Comment: That depends on the implementation of those functions.

Comment: If that's the data structure, it would be 1, N, 1 and 1. If you keep the size in the header, they would all be 1.

Comment: This is a review question i have, we are not given more information other than what I just provided. Is there any way to determine it just using the information above?

Comment: I would say N, N, 1 and 1, because you need to free each structure on the stack, not just the top. If you used a mark/release style allocator you could get that first number to 1.

Comment: If it's about general abstract data structure, I suggest you read and understand the *stack* data structure and you'll be able to answer these questions yourself. Trust me, it's *not* that hard ;-)

Comment: I assumed StackEmpty() just meant boolean if the stack is empty or not; not "free all the stack".

Comment: Charlie did you read my comment "This is a review question i have, we are not given more information other than what I just provided. Is there any way to determine it just using the information above?". So this is all the info i was given :(.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity

- StackEmpty(Stack *s)    = O(1) //we need to check only  `top== null` or not
- StackSize(Stack *s)     = O(n) //we need to pop n time  `count++` if stack holds n elements that is until `top== null`
- Push(Node *e, Stack *s) = O(1) //requires only one operation no Explanation need for this i asume
- Pop(Node *e, Stack *s)  = O(1) //requires only one operation no Explanation need for this i asume

---

```
Boolean StackEmpty(Stack *s)

{
    if(s.Next==null&&s.value==null)
        return true; //or 1
    else
        return false; //or 0
}

int StackSize(Stack *s)
{
    if(StackEmpty!=true)
    {
        count = 0
        while(StackEmpty!=true)
        { 
           pop();
          Count++;
        }
     }
     return Count;
 }
```